# i want to store list item in session id licitys, but cant do it can have any suggestion

Tags: c#, javascript, html, mysql

js:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#licity li").click(function () {
         alert($(this).text());

        Session["licitys"] =$(this).text();

     });
 });
```

and this session id put into sql query of another aspx page.

the c# code of another page:

```
 GlobalClass.adap = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from ab_db.dic where city_name='"+ Session["licitys"] +"'", con);
```

Comment: I also try in parameterized query, another session id working properly but another one which was stored using javascript not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it using cookies.
may not good decision but it was worked for me